# Delphi ~ Memory Leak in JSON

Tags: json, delphi

Using Delphi 10.4.1 on Windows and Mobile.  I have a memory leak using this code in Windows. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
oResultJO := TJSONObject.Create;
try
  oSecondJO := TJSONObject.Create;
  oFirstJO := TJSONObject.Create;
  oFirstJO.AddPair('TYPE_1', TJSONNumber.Create(1));
  oFirstJO.AddPair('TYPE_1', TJSONNumber.Create(2));
  oSecondJO.AddPair('TYPE_2', TJSONNumber.Create(3));

  if (oFirstJO.Count > 0) then
    oResultJO.AddPair('FIRST', oFirstJO)
  else
    oFirstJO.Free;

  if (oSecondJO.Count > 0) then
  begin
    oResultJO.AddPair('SECOND', oSecondJO);
  end else
    oSecondJO.Free;

  showmessage(oResultJO.ToString);
finally
  oResultJO.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I see no leak in this code (unless an exception is raised, in which case you have the potential for up to 5 leaks, depending on where the exception is raised from). The code is fine (though it could use some better error handling). What makes you think there is actually a leak? FYI, your `if`s are redundant since the `Count`s are both guaranteed to be `> 0`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks and noted.  The "if" was there because in actual longer code, the Count may not > 0.  Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Then you need to provide a [mcve] that is more representative of your real code and demonstrates the leak in action.

Comment: Comment out the content completely and add the individual lines successively. Where did you get the statement about a memory leak from?

Comment: The most likely mistake would be to fail to notice RemovePair has a result that needs to be freed if <> nil (don't ask :P).  Considering you're saying `the Count may not > 0`, I suspect this may be the issue. (Which would also mean you removed the very part that is causing the problem from your question).

Comment: i dont know from where you know you have a leak. For windows i use Fast MM4 (Dual License) [FastMM4 Readme](https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4/blob/master/FastMM4_Readme.txt) Search for "FullDebugMode" This helped me every Time i had something like that. (a newer Version 5 is available but i only know Version 4, which is also the default Memorymanager (on windows?) since XE?)

Comment: Further to what @ KenBourassa mentioned, if (oFirstJO.Count > 0) then oResultJO.AddPair('FIRST', oFirstJO) else     oFirstJO.Free;  -- would this cause a problem if oFirstJO.Free is called (since it is not added to AddPair - it needs to be freed manually?) instead of the AddPair

Comment: My thanks to all to confirming above code has no leak.  I found out the problem was that my inherited frame was destructor Destroy; instead of destructor Destroy; override; in the declaration, but it resulted in it saying there was a JSON leak, which threw me off track.